# Compiling fails when creating MapFunction with super type

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink 1.12.0, and I have following simple test case:

I defined two model class(AbstractDataModel is super type, while the ConcreteModel is the sub type):

```
public interface AbstractDataModel {
    public String getValue();
}

public class ConcreteModel implements AbstractDataModel {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public ConcreteModel() {
    }

    public ConcreteModel(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then, I define a simple application as follows,which is to map the ConcreteModel to string,

The MapFunction is using the super type AbstractDataModel, but there is compiling error complaining:

```
Required type:
MapFunction<com.ConcreteModel,java.lang.String>
Provided:
MyMapFunction
```

I would ask how to fix this problem if I still want to use AbstractDataModel as the generic type in the MapFunction

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

class MyMapFunction implements MapFunction<AbstractDataModel, String> {

    public String map(AbstractDataModel model) throws Exception {
        return model.getValue();
    }
}

public class ConcreteModelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        //        env.registerType(ConcreteModel.class);
        //        env.registerType(AbstractDataModel.class);
        //
        DataStream<String> ds = env.fromElements(new ConcreteModel("a", "1"), new ConcreteModel("b", "2")).map(new MyMapFunction());
        ds.print();
        env.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens basically because Flink cannot process `POJO` objects due to its distributed environment. Here is what says the [docs](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html):

> 15:45:51,460 INFO org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor -
> Class … cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid
> POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the
> Flink documentation on “Data Types & Serialization” for details of the
> effect on performance.

You can use the [ResultTypeQueryable](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/typeutils/ResultTypeQueryable.html) and define the return type with `TypeInformation.of(AbstractDataModel.class)` on the method `public TypeInformation getProducedType()`.

> This interface can be implemented by functions and input formats to
> tell the framework about their produced data type. This method acts as
> an alternative to the reflection analysis that is otherwise performed
> and is useful in situations where the produced data type may vary
> depending on parametrization.

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.ResultTypeQueryable;

public class MyMapFunction implements MapFunction<AbstractDataModel, String>, 
    ResultTypeQueryable {

    @Override
    public String map(AbstractDataModel value) throws Exception {
        return value.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(AbstractDataModel.class);
    }
}
public class ConcreteModelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        AbstractDataModel concreteModel01 = new ConcreteModel("a", "1");
        AbstractDataModel concreteModel02 = new ConcreteModel("a", "2");
        DataStream<String> ds = env
                .fromElements(concreteModel01, concreteModel02)
                .map(new MyMapFunction());
        ds.print();
        env.execute();
    }
}
```

or an easy way is to just call `map` with `TypeInformation.of(String.class)`. Then you don't need to implement `ResultTypeQueryable` at `MyMapFunction`.

```
DataStream<String> ds = env
    .fromElements(concreteModel01, concreteModel02)
    .map(new MyMapFunction(), TypeInformation.of(String.class));
```

and then just use your interface with its class implementation.

```
public interface AbstractDataModel {
    public String getValue();
}
public class ConcreteModel implements AbstractDataModel {
    private String key;
    private String value;
    public ConcreteModel() {
    }
    public ConcreteModel(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @felipe helping me out. I play with your code and get a question: what does it mean for MyMapFunction implementing ResultTypeQueryable<AbstractDataModel>?  MyMapFunction `accepts` an AbstractDataModel and produces a string. With ResultTypeQueryable, MyMapFunction 
 looks producing AbstractDataModel?

Comment: Hi @felipe,could you please help take a look at my comment above? I don't understand why MyMapFunction#getProducedType returns TypeInformation<AbstractDataMode>, since it accepts an AbstractDataMode and produce a string？

Comment: The doc says that we can set the input format: `Gets the data type (as a TypeInformation) produced by this function or input format`. I also think that name of the method it is kind of confunsing. Unfortunetelly this is the best info that I could find.

Comment: Thanks @felipe for the helpful answer!