# javadoc of SingleOutputStreamOperator#returns(TypeHint<T> typeHint) method

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am reading the source code of `SingleOutputStreamOperator#returns`, its javadoc is:

```
/**
 * Adds a type information hint about the return type of this operator. This method
 * can be used in cases where Flink cannot determine automatically what the produced
 * type of a function is. That can be the case if the function uses generic type variables
 * in the return type that cannot be inferred from the input type.
 *
 * <p>Use this method the following way:
 * <pre>{@code
 *     DataStream<Tuple2<String, Double>> result =
 *         stream.flatMap(new FunctionWithNonInferrableReturnType())
 *               .returns(new TypeHint<Tuple2<String, Double>>(){});
 * }</pre>
 *
 * @param typeHint The type hint for the returned data type.
 * @return This operator with the type information corresponding to the given type hint.
 */
```

It mentions `FunctionWithNonInferrableReturnType` to show case the necessity of returns method, but I am unable to write such a class that is `NonInferrableReturnType`. How can I write a simple one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the docs says `NonInferrableReturnType` it means that we can use the type variable `<T>`, or any other letter that you prefer. So you can create a `MapFunction` that return a `T`. But then you have to use `.returns(TypeInformation.of(String.class)` for example, if your goal is to return a `String`.

```
public class MyMapFunctionNonInferrableReturnType<T> implements MapFunction<AbstractDataModel, T> {
    @Override
    public T map(AbstractDataModel value) throws Exception {
        return (T) value.getValue();
    }
}
```

Here I am using the classes of your last question [Compiling fails when creating MapFunction with super type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68174020/2096986) . The same code without `.returns(TypeInformation.of(String.class))` compiles but throw the runtime exception:

> could not be determined automatically, due to type erasure. You can
> give type information hints by using the returns(...) method on the
> result of the transformation call, or by letting your function
> implement the 'ResultTypeQueryable' interface.

```
public class NonInferrableReturnTypeStreamJob {

    private final List<AbstractDataModel> abstractDataModelList;
    private final ValenciaSinkFunction sink;

    public NonInferrableReturnTypeStreamJob() {
        this.abstractDataModelList = new ArrayList<AbstractDataModel>();
        this.abstractDataModelList.add(new ConcreteModel("a", "1"));
        this.abstractDataModelList.add(new ConcreteModel("a", "2"));
        this.sink = new ValenciaSinkFunction();
    }

    public NonInferrableReturnTypeStreamJob(List<AbstractDataModel> abstractDataModelList, ValenciaSinkFunction sink) {
        this.abstractDataModelList = abstractDataModelList;
        this.sink = sink;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NonInferrableReturnTypeStreamJob concreteModelTest = new NonInferrableReturnTypeStreamJob();
        concreteModelTest.execute();
    }

    public void execute() throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.fromCollection(this.abstractDataModelList)
                .map(new MyMapFunctionNonInferrableReturnType())
                .returns(TypeInformation.of(String.class))
                .addSink(sink);

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

In case you wish, here is the integration test for this example:

```
import org.apache.flink.runtime.testutils.MiniClusterResourceConfiguration;
import org.apache.flink.test.util.MiniClusterWithClientResource;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.sense.flink.examples.stream.valencia.ValenciaSinkFunction;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class NonInferrableReturnTypeStreamJobTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static MiniClusterWithClientResource flinkCluster;
    private final int minAvailableProcessors = 4;
    private final boolean runInParallel;

    public NonInferrableReturnTypeStreamJobTest() {
        int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        this.runInParallel = availableProcessors >= minAvailableProcessors;
        if (this.runInParallel) {
            flinkCluster = new MiniClusterWithClientResource(
                    new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
                            .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(minAvailableProcessors)
                            .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
                            .build());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void execute() throws Exception {
        List<AbstractDataModel> abstractDataModelList = new ArrayList<AbstractDataModel>();
        abstractDataModelList.add(new ConcreteModel("a", "1"));
        abstractDataModelList.add(new ConcreteModel("a", "2"));
        ValenciaSinkFunction.values.clear();

        NonInferrableReturnTypeStreamJob streamJob = new NonInferrableReturnTypeStreamJob(abstractDataModelList, new ValenciaSinkFunction());
        streamJob.execute();

        List<String> results = ValenciaSinkFunction.values;
        assertEquals(2, results.size());
        assertTrue(results.containsAll(Arrays.asList("1", "2")));
    }
}
```