# flink how to integration test unbounded stream, main method is running indefinitely

Tags: integration-testing, apache-flink

I have a main method to run a Flink job which is in last calling *env.execute()*  method for trigger the flink job, while I was running test, it is running indefinitely, what I'm doing wrong.

```
 @ClassRule
  public static DockerComposeContainer environment =
      new DockerComposeContainer(new File("docker-compose.yml"))
          .withExposedService("zookeeper_1", 2181)
          .withExposedService("kafka_1", 29092);

  @ClassRule
  public static MiniClusterResource flinkCluster =
      new MiniClusterResource(
          new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
              .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(2)
              .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
              .build());
   @Test
  public void testMain() throws Exception {
    
    // trigger job, it create flink env, run a map function on unbounded stream, and at  last call execute method 
    StreamingJob.main(null);

    // code execution not coming here
    assert (4 == 4);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is normal for streaming jobs to run forever, unless they have bounded inputs. For testing you want to make sure that your input isn't unbounded -- so, for example, if you are implementing an integration test that reads from Kafka, you will want to use a deserializer that eventually returns true from `isEndOfStream`.

Comment: The new KafkaSource works a bit differently. Now you can use `setBounded` to establish the upper bound for a range of offsets.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are calling the static method of your `StreamingJob`. You have some how call a method that inside it has the:

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
   StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
   StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
   // env.YOUR_DATASTREAM_PIPELINE
   env.execute();
}
```

then your integration test will be something like:

```
  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    
    StreamingJob streamJob = new StreamingJob();
    streamJob.execute();

    // execute your assertions
  }
```

take a look at this example of this [integration test for Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68191546/2096986).